# Irrational numbers are non-terminating/non-repeating decimals

Tags: irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Why is it true that all irrational numbers are non-terminating/non-repeating decimals?

By definition, an irrational number is one that can't be expressed as a ratio of integers.

Comment: Unclear what the question is: are you asking why they are non-terminating, why they are non-repeating, or why they can't be expressed as a ratio of integers?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to know a irrationals never repeat?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/482586)

Comment: All of the above.

Comment: Still unclear, because one of those things is a definition of irrational number. _And_ too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know that irrational numbers never repeat?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482586/how-to-know-that-irrational-numbers-never-repeat)

Comment: @DwayneRousseau Welcome to Math.SE! Be sure to search for questions before asking them, since as Normal Human indicates the answer already exists on the site.

Comment: Dajani/Kraaikamp's *Ergodic Theory of Numbers* does this.

Comment: For what it's worth I'd keep this open as it's clear that the OP would like to know why this is true and how it fits in with the definition.  And for that there *is* a very clear and precise answer.  But I'd vote to close it as it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The definition: a number is irrational if and only if it's not rational, i.e. it can't be expressed as a ratio of two integers. This answers one part of your question.

The other part: I'll prove the contrapositive. If $x$ has a repeating decimal expansion (this includes terminating decimal expansions), then $x$ is rational.

Proof: If $x$ has a repeating decimal expansion, then it can always be written in the following form:

Let $c,b$ be non-negative integers and $a_i\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ and $t$ is the number of digits of $b$.
$$x=\overline{c.ba_1a_2\ldots a_ka_1a_2\ldots a_ka_1a_2\ldots}$$
$$10^tx=\overline{cb.a_1a_2\ldots a_ka_2a_2\ldots a_ka_1a_2\ldots}$$
$$10^{kt}x=\overline{cba_1a_2\ldots a_k.a_1a_2\ldots a_ka_1a_2\ldots}$$
$$10^{kt}x-10^{t}x=\overline{cba_1a_2\ldots a_k}-\overline{cb}$$
$$x=\frac{\overline{cba_1a_2\ldots a_k}-\overline{cb}}{10^{kt}-10^t}$$

Comment: Thanks, user236182; I now understand the reasoning.

Comment: Wait, what if we have 1.2(3)? Then k=1 and we will get division by zero in the end!

Answer (score 0):

- If the decimal expansion of a number $x$ is terminating, with $n$ digits after the decimal point, say, then $10^nx$ is an integer $m$ (the decimal expansion is shifted by $n$ places to the left, hence has nothing after the decimal point) so that $x =\frac{m}{10^n}$ is a fraction of integers, aka. rational number.
- If the decimal expansion of a number $x$ is eventually repeating, with a epriod of length $n\ge1$, say, then $10^nx$ has  a decimal expansion that matches that of $x$ beyond some point, so that in computing $10^nx-x$ everything cancels beyond some point, i.e., $10^nx-x$ is a rational $\frac ab$ per first bullet point. Solving for $x$ we find $x=\frac{a}{(10^n-1)b}$, which is again a fraction of integers.
- If $x$ is the ratio/fraction of integers, then *by definition* it is rational.

Hence for an *irrational* number (by definition a number that is *not* a rational number)  none of the three options above can occur.

Comment: Thanks, Hagen von Eitzen for this, for I get it now.